# Story proof for choosing committee with pre-designated president

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, combinatorial-proofs

The problem is to come up with story proof for the following:

Show that for all positive integers n and k with n $\geq$ k, $$\mathbf{\binom{n}{k}+ \binom{n}{k-1} = \binom{n+1}{k}},$$ doing this with a story, giving an interpretation for why both sides count the same thing.
Hint for the story proof: Imagine n + 1 people, with one of them pre-designated as “president”.

The [explanation](https://premmi.github.io/probability-story-proofs-part-I#:%7E:text=Suppose%20from%20a%20group,LHS%7D%24%20of%20the%20identity.) I found is following:

> Suppose from a group of $\mathbf{n+1}$ people we have to form a
> committee comprising of $\mathbf{k}$ people. Also in this group one
> person is pre-designated as president. The number of ways of forming
> this committee is given by $\mathbf{\binom{n+1}{k}}$ which is the
> **right-hand side** of the identity. We can also think of forming the committee in two ways, one in which the president $\mathbf{is}$ chosen
> and out of the remaining $\mathbf{n}$ people we choose $\mathbf{k-1}$
> and one in which the president is $\mathbf{not}$ chosen and we choose
> $\mathbf{k}$ people from $\mathbf{n}$ people. Summing these two cases
> we get $\mathbf{\binom{n}{k-1} + \binom{n}{k}}$ which is the
> **left-hand side** of the identity.

I have no questions regarding the second term "*n choose k*" — the (n+1)th person that was left out is the pre-designated as president.
However the first term baffles me. If the (n+1)th person isn't a president than how the term can account for all group, and how the committee is guaranteed to include the pre-designated president.

I know that I probably don't understand something obvious and would be grateful if someone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: For me the translation of "choosing form $n+1$ a committee of $k$ people of which $1$ is president" would lead to the identity ${n+1 \choose k}{k \choose 1} = {n+1 \choose 1}{n \choose k-1}$

Comment: @Henry a president is *pre*-designated.

Comment: You are forming a committee of $k$ people from a set of $n+1$ people. The committee **may or may not** include a special person designated as the president. If it doesn't then that means the committee was formed from the remaining $n$ folks. If the special person **is in** the committee then you only have to choose remaining $k-1$ folks from $n$ people.

Comment: @AnuragA If I understand you, you are saying the predesignated special person is president of the committee if a member but not if not.  Wouldn't it be simpler to say the special person is either a member of the committee or not, and ignore the question of president?

Comment: @Henry There is no president of "the" committee. I used the word president because OP used it. You are correct, in saying a special person (say $\alpha$) is either in the committee or not and that $\alpha$ is identified ahead of the selection.

Comment: @AnuragA Thanks, got it. A pre-designated president doesn't influence the formation of the committee. It could be just *any* particular person from (n+1) group.

Answer (score 1):

For me the translation of "choosing form $n+1$ a committee of $k$ people of which $1$ is president" would lead to the identity $${n+1 \choose k}{k \choose 1} = {n+1 \choose 1}{n \choose k-1}$$

For the identity you are showing, you can either select the committee from the first $n$ people so ${n\choose k}$ ways, or choose $k-1$ from the first $n$ and then also choose the $n+1^{\text{th}}$ person so  ${n\choose k-1}$ times $1$, but these need to sum to the more natural ${n+1\choose k}$, leading to $${n\choose k}+{n\choose k-1}={n+1\choose k}$$ but this does not involve predesignating somebody as president

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but I think you are not understanding how the $\binom{n}{k-1}$ is formed.

---

Assume that the $(n-1)^{\text{th}}$ person is the president. We already counted the case when the president isn't in the $k$ chosen people in $\binom{n}{k}$, so in this case the president **IS** in the $k$-person committee. We have $(n+1)-1 = n$ people left to choose from after we have included the president in the committee, and we need $k-1$ more people in our committee as we have already chosen $1$ (the president) to be one of the $k$ people. Thus, in this part where the president **IS** included in the $k$-person committee gives $\boxed{\binom{n}{k-1}}$